# Is this a good translation?

Tags: grammar, translation

This is an excerpt from an English translation of the Shreecharitmanasa that I tried to translate. I simplified it slightly so I could practice.

> I worship Ganesh(Kanesya) & Saraswati(Sarasupati), the inventors of writing and poetry and their meaning.

내가 숭배하는 가네샤와 사라스바티는 문자와 시와 그 의미의 창조자입니다 창조자이다.

"their meaning" should apply to both "writing" and "poetry" here.

Would this translation make sense? What could I change to make it flow better?

Answer (score 2):

I would say 내가 숭배하는 가네샤와 사라스바티는 문자와 시와 그 의미의 창조자입니다 is a good translation with no obvious flaws.

One thing to note is that 문자 is more like *written language* or even *symbols/characters in a language*.  Depending on what exactly "writing" means in the original, you might try different words like 산문 (prose) or 글쓰기 (*writing* in a more mundane sense) or something else.

If you want to make it extra clear that "their meaning" applies to both 문자 and 시, you could say 이들의 의미의 instead of 그 의미의.  그 is basically singular, but since Korean doesn't specify number for every noun the way English does, 그 can be used for both singular and plural noun - that is, the number is undefined.  If you add 들 which is the plurality suffix in Korean, it makes the term explicitly plural and thus apply to both 문자 and 시 without ambiguity.  If you do this, 이들 (these) usually sounds better than 그들 (those) when referring to abstract, inanimate things as in this case.  So you might substitute 문자와 시와 이들의 의미의 창조자입니다.  Another (poorer sounding) option is 그것들의 (*their* referring to things not nearby) or 이것들의 (*their* referring to things nearby).

In most cases though, 그 의미의 is good enough and it might even sound smoother.